# How to return data from a fragment using androidx.navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I open a selection fragment using androidx.navigation, but I cannot find a way to return data to the previous fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one parent activity.. just use global variable that able to access inside same parent activity or

Other trick you can try preference, so that preference will able to read anywhere you want.

Data share active fragment

```
sharedPref =  context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(),MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
prefEditor.putString(sKey, sValue);
prefEditor.apply();
```

Data read from other fragment

```
sharedPref =  context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(),MODE_PRIVATE);
sValue = sharedPref.getString(sKey,defValue);
```

Comment: Thank's to [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) for editing language, it's more beautiful and easy to read